# Reading & storing chrome Developer tool network data

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I want to capture Chrome developer tool network data, either using java/javascript code or using automation tool like selenium2 webdriver.

```
1) I want to capture name of fired event from the network tab.
2) I need to get "Request URL" (from Header) info for that particular captured name.
```

Any thoughts would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture any data from chrome's developer console, as it's scope is not within webdriver's one. What you can really do is to use browsermob-proxy (and it's java/javascript/php etc bindings):

https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

You can capture response data with [cdp4j](https://github.com/webfolderio/cdp4j). Please review [this](https://github.com/webfolderio/cdp4j/blob/master/src/test/java/io/webfolder/cdp/sample/NetworkResponse.java) sample code to dump all response data.